# How to get a numbered variable names in the array?

Tags: c, linux

I want to get the following variable names in the array:

```
part1, part2, part3, part4...
```

Here are excerpts from the program code:

```
#define argument(x) #x
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
names[i]=strcat("part", argument(i));
```

As I think, after pre-processing I get instead of `#var` - `"var"`.
But instead that i get `sigmentation fault`.

How to solve this problem. Maybe there are other methods?

Comment: Use `snprintf()` instead.

Comment: Literal strings (`"part"`) cannot be modified. That is the cause of your seg fault. Create a buffer variable and use `snprintf` as @iharob said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as recommended:

```
char names[10][100];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  snprintf(names[i], sizeof(names[i]), "part%d",i);
}
```

Comment: `100` ==better==> `sizeof(names[i])`

Comment: @JohnHascall yeah that's better, I tried to show OP main approach to his problem.

Comment: Why do we use two-dimensional array? Is it instead the malloc function? As I understood - the first dimension is for 0-10 part, the second one - is the size of the var's names?

Comment: @MaximGusev: I don't know, it seemed to me you wanted those strings to be stored as array of strings; yes second dimension is length of each string. If you don't know first dimension apriori, you may need to allocate first dimension of array dynamically, and thus use pointer to pointer instead.